# How to resize the new uploaded images using PIL before saving?

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, django-models

I want to resize the new images in a height and width of 800px and save them. And the app mustn't store the real image. Any help?

This is my code, it saves the original image and don't the resized photo:

models.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):        
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/default/')


    def save(self):

        if not self.id and not self.photo:
            return            

        super(Photo, self).save()

        image = Image.open(self.photo)
        (width, height) = image.size

        "Max width and height 800"        
        if (800 / width < 800 / height):
            factor = 800 / height
        else:
            factor = 800 / width

        size = ( width / factor, height / factor)
        image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(self.photo.path)
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code you have? You haven't said what it's doing wrong. The code you've shown will save the image to the DB. If you don't want to save the un-resized image you have to resize if before it's saved - i.e. at the form level

Comment: @pastylegs At the form level which method I should be use and how?

Comment: Are you uploading through the django admin or using a custom form?

Comment: Throug a custom form. The first answer solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone uses that code for some reason, there are a few mistakes on the factor part: factor should be a float (ie, 800.0 / width), you should multiply factor when setting on the size (not divide!), remember to cast back to int when setting the size, and the < should be an >. Besides, of course, the fix of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

resize is non-destructive, it returns a new image.

Comment: I know, but how I save the resized photo without saving the original?

Comment: replace the line "image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)" with "image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)"  Right now you're resizing but ignoring the result and saving the original image.

Answer (score 14):

I use [django-resized](https://github.com/un1t/django-resized) for my projects.

Comment: +1 because this project works perfectly out of the box with django-storages+boto.  Excellent, saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: this project didn't work out of the box with django storages + boto, broke file upload for me from the api

Comment: I liked it as well; since the project is so small actually i just copied the form class and used it...

Answer (score 4):

I searched for a solution to resize uploaded photo before saving.  There are a lot of info bit and bit here and there (in StackOverflow).  Yet, no complete solution.  Here is my final solution that I think works for people who wants it.

**Development Highlight**

- Using Pillow for image processing (two packages required: libjpeg-dev, zlib1g-dev)
- Using Model and ImageField as storage
- Using HTTP POST or PUT with multipart/form
- No need to save the file to disk manually.
- Create multiple resolutions and stores their dimensions.
- Did not modify the Model itself

**Install Pillow**

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
$ pip install -I Pillow
```

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True)
    image_w = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image_h = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', default=None, 
                blank=True, width_field='image_w', height_field='image_h')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', default=None,
                blank=True)
```

This model saves a photo with thumbnail and an optional caption.  This should be similar to the real-world use case.

Our goal is to resize the photo to 640x640 and generate a 150x150 thumbnail.  We also need to return the dimension of the photo in our web API. `image_w` and `image_h` is a cached dimension in table.  Note that we need to add quota ' when we declare an ImageField.  However, `thumbnail` does not need the width and height field (so you can see the different).

That's the model.  We don't need to override or add any functions to the model.

**myapp/serializers.py**

We will use a `ModelSerializer` to process the incoming data from HTTP POST.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapp.models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('caption',)
```

We do not want the serializer to handle the uploaded photo - we will do it ourself.  So, no need to include 'image' in fields.

**myapp/views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((MultiPartParser,))
def handle_uploaded_image(request):
    # process images first.  if error, quit.
    if not 'uploaded_media' in request.FILES:
        return Response({'msg': 'Photo missing.'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    try:
        im = Image.open(StringIO(request.FILES['uploaded_media'].read()))
    except IOError:
        return Response({'msg': 'Bad image.'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({'msg': serializer.errors}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    post = Post.create()
    if serializer.data['caption'] is not None:
        post.caption = serializer.data['caption']

    filename = uuid.uuid4()
    name = '%s_0.jpg' % (filename)
    post.image.save(name=name, content=resize_image(im, 640))
    name = '%s_1.jpg' % (filename)
    post.thumbnail.save(name=name, content=resize_image(im, 150))

    post.save()
    return Response({'msg': 'success',
        'caption': post.caption,
        'image': {
            'url': request.build_absolute_uri(post.image.url),
            'width': post.image_w,
            'height': post.image_h,
        }
        'thumbnail': request.build_absolute_uri(post.thumbnail.url),
    }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**helper functions in a shared py**

```
def resize_image(im, edge):
    (width, height) = im.size
    (width, height) = scale_dimension(w, h, long_edge=edge)
    content = StringIO()
    im.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS).save(fp=content, format='JPEG', dpi=[72, 72])
    return ContentFile(content.getvalue())

def scale_dimension(width, height, long_edge):
    if width > height:
        ratio = long_edge * 1. / width
    else:
        ratio = long_edge * 1. / height
    return int(width * ratio), int(height * ratio)
```

Here, we do not use Image.thumbnail because it will change the original image.  This code is suitable if we want to store multiple resolutions (such as low res and high res for different purpose).  I found that resizing the incoming message twice will degrade the quality.

We also do not save the image directly to disk.  We push the image via a ContentFile (a File object for content in memory) to ImageField and let the ImageField do its job.  We wants the multiple copies of image have the same file name with different postfix.

**Credits**

Here are the links of codes that I had references to build this solution:

- Use of ContentFile in ImageField.save, by Martey: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7022005/3731039
- Use of StringIO for reading multipart/form, by johndoevodka: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523422/3731039
- Code for resizing: http://davedash.com/2009/02/21/resizing-image-on-upload-in-django/

If you want to validate the image as well, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20762344/3731039

Answer (score 1):

here is what worked for me, inspired a little from django-resized

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyUser)
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Gruppo)
def ridimensiona_immagine(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    foto = instance.foto

    foto.file.seek(0)
    thumb = PIL.Image.open(foto.file)
    thumb.thumbnail((
        200, 
        200
        ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)


    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    thumb.save(buffer, "PNG")
    image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(buffer, None, 'test.png', 'image/png', buffer.len, None)

    instance.foto.file = image_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python < 3, you should consider using :

```
from __future__ import division
```

In this case the result number of your division will be float.

Comment: Using ```//``` may be a better option though, as the rest of the code may assume division results will be float.

Comment: This seems to be completely off topic :-/

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet test this solution, but it might help!!

```
#subidas.py
import PIL
from PIL import Image
def achichar_tamanho(path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    img = img.resize((230,230), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(path)
```

In your `models.py`, make the following changes:

```
from subidas import achicar_tamanho

class Productos(models.Model):
    imagen = models.ImageField(default="emg_bol/productos/interrogacion.png", upload_to='emg_bol/productos/', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Image of the product")
    tiempo_ultima_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField( help_text="Cuando fue la ultima vez, que se modificaron los datos de este producto", auto_now=True)
    prioridad = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, default=99, help_text="Frecuencia (medida en unidad), con que el producto es despachado para la venta")
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedores, help_text="El que provello del producto'")  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Productos,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        pcod = "%s_%s" % ( re.sub('\s+', '', self.descripcion)[:3], self.id)
        self.producto_cod = pcod
        achichar_tamanho(self.imagen.path)
        super(Productos,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I really don't know, what was the difference before and after implementing these changes.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is to use this method to resize the image in the form before saving it: (you need `pip install pillow`)

```
import os
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as PilImage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile, TemporaryUploadedFile

def resize_uploaded_image(image, max_width, max_height):
    size = (max_width, max_height)

    # Uploaded file is in memory
    if isinstance(image, InMemoryUploadedFile):
        memory_image = BytesIO(image.read())
        pil_image = PilImage.open(memory_image)
        img_format = os.path.splitext(image.name)[1][1:].upper()
        img_format = 'JPEG' if img_format == 'JPG' else img_format

        if pil_image.width > max_width or pil_image.height > max_height:
            pil_image.thumbnail(size)

        new_image = BytesIO()
        pil_image.save(new_image, format=img_format)

        new_image = ContentFile(new_image.getvalue())
        return InMemoryUploadedFile(new_image, None, image.name, image.content_type, None, None)

    # Uploaded file is in disk
    elif isinstance(image, TemporaryUploadedFile):
        path = image.temporary_file_path()
        pil_image = PilImage.open(path)

        if pil_image.width > max_width or pil_image.height > max_height:
            pil_image.thumbnail(size)
            pil_image.save(path)
            image.size = os.stat(path).st_size

    return image
```

Then use it in the clean method of the image field in your form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    IMAGE_WIDTH = 450
    IMAGE_HEIGHT = 450
    
    image = forms.ImageField()

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        image = resize_uploaded_image(image, self.IMAGE_WIDTH, self.IMAGE_HEIGHT)
        return image
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me Django resized does the trick and it is very easy to understand just pip install it and have a look at the docs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).